# Telerik MVC Grid groups with key, display, and sort values?

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I'm running a grid with Ajax binding with added groups:

```
.Groupable(grouping => grouping
    .Groups(groups =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < TagGroups.Count; i++)
        {
           groups.Add(c => c.Tags[i].Name);
        }
    })
)
```

This is grouping the data by the **Name** property. In essence, the **Name** property is being used for three jobs. It is acting as the group key, it is the displaying value, and is used to sort the groups alphabetically.

I want to specify the property for each of these jobs. I want the **Id** property to act as the group key, the **Name** property to act as the display value, and the **Order** property to act as the sort value numerically instead of alphabetically.

If this is a tall order, I can live with the **Name** property as the group key and display value, but I need to specify the **Order** property as the sort value. Any thoughts? I'd prefer **not** tinkering with back-end data with Linq or such, because It makes a lot of sense to just configure a Telerik Grid to do this.

Comment: Basically, how can I change the order method from alphabetical of the group value to numerical of the group's Order property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Name & Order are bound columns in the grid. Use only Order in the Groupable list. Then in your grid DataBound(), replace each order with the corresponding Name property.